# How to add custom secure (privacy) screen on the app switcher

Tags: flutter, privacy

I want to add a secure (privacy) screen feature (hide content when the app is in background). There are many packages that provide similar functionality, but almost all of them just blur the app screen ([secure_app_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/secure_app_switcher), [privacy_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/privacy_screen), [secure_application](https://pub.dev/packages/secure_application)). I want to show my logo on a white/black background (depending on the app theme). How I can achieve this?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try secure_application package there is SecureGate provide what you wants, package is old maybe you need fix something in it.

'Put the content you want to protect in a SecureGate (could be the whole app)'

```
SecureGate(
      blurr: 5,
      lockedBuilder: (context, secureNotifier) => Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('test'),
        onPressed: () => secureNotifier.unlock(),
      )),
      child: YouProtectedWidget(),
```

)

Comment: Yeah, this package is too old